# How can I interact with a API in NiFi with InvokeHttp?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to do a simple http POST request from NiFi (Windows 10).
I want to send a JSON

[image]

I configured the "SSL Context Service" in StandardSSLContextService, and then the controller:

- The Truststore filename is : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\lib\security\cacerts
- password: changeit

[image]

But there is a problem.

[image]

I try without this configuration and also I have an error.

I can't understand how to solve the problem to interact with a simple API.

Comment: Is the service presenting a certificate that is signed by one of the CA's in cacerts? That error usually means the truststore does not trust the cert that was presented.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know nothing about certificate. I configured with a tutorial, because without this configuration also gave me another error. How is possible make a simple post request? Or I need to configure other things in NiFi?

Comment: Well unfortunately you will need to know about the certificate... is the API a public API that you can connect to in your browser? or is it an internal API?

Comment: With Postman, I can connect with the API, (disable the ssl certificate verification).

Comment: Ok well if you had to disable the verification to connect then it likely means the certificate the service is presenting is not signed by one of the major CAs that would be in cacerts, so unfortunately you'll have to create a custom truststore that trusts the cert

Comment: Thank you. And how can I do this custom trustore? And what resources do you recommend me to read/watch to learn to solve it?

Comment: This has decent steps to create the truststore.jks - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.conn.filecon.usage.doc/topics/filecon_t_enable_ssl_connect.html

Comment: You first need to get the server cert in pem format - https://medium.com/@menakajain/export-download-ssl-certificate-from-server-site-url-bcfc41ea46a2

Comment: Sorry, but for understand the problem. The problem is NiFi or the API's server? NiFi only work with secure API?

Comment: The problem is the API's server certificate is likely a self-signed certificate, so it is not trusted by default by browser/postman/nifi and nifi doesn't allow you to disable verification because that is bad security practice

Answer (score 0):

@Alan Mejia

You should setup your keystore and trustore (both) using cacerts.  Then test your solution.    Make sure nifi has permissions to access the file. I usually copy the java file to a nifi specific location, and then copy to all nifi nodes owned to nifi user.   Last but not least, you may have to modifiy the TLS type, try them all until one works.

If the cacerts file does not work,  you will need to get the APIs public cert and then build a custom keystore/trustore by importing that cert.  Try the cacerts thoroughly before taking this route.